# Parameter scope vs local variable scope?

Tags: java, variables, parameters, scope, local-variables

I was reading my AP cs book and it talked about three types of variables:

•Instance variables

•Local variables

•Parameters

Instance variables are visible throughout the class etc...
Parameters are only usable within the method and so are local variables . . .

Therefore my question is why would they classify Parameters and Local variables as different categories of variables if they contain the same scope. . . Despite the different uses of them.

Answer (score 4):

The [Java Language Specification identifies 7 types of variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3). Their descriptions are

> A **class variable** is a field declared using the keyword static within a
>   class declaration (§8.3.1.1), or with or without the keyword static
>   within an interface declaration (§9.3).
>
> A class variable is created when its class or interface is prepared
>   (§12.3.2) and is initialized to a default value (§4.12.5). The class
>   variable effectively ceases to exist when its class or interface is
>   unloaded (§12.7).
>
> An **instance variable** is a field declared within a class declaration
>   without using the keyword static (§8.3.1.1).
>
> If a class T has a field a that is an instance variable, then a new
>   instance variable a is created and initialized to a default value
>   (§4.12.5) as part of each newly created object of class T or of any
>   class that is a subclass of T (§8.1.4). The instance variable
>   effectively ceases to exist when the object of which it is a field is
>   no longer referenced, after any necessary finalization of the object
>   (§12.6) has been completed.
>
> **Array components are unnamed variables** that are created and
>   initialized to default values (§4.12.5) whenever a new object that is
>   an array is created (§10, §15.10). The array components effectively
>   cease to exist when the array is no longer referenced.
>
> **Method parameters** (§8.4.1) name argument values passed to a method.
>
> For every parameter declared in a method declaration, a new parameter
>   variable is created each time that method is invoked (§15.12). The new
>   variable is initialized with the corresponding argument value from the
>   method invocation. The method parameter effectively ceases to exist
>   when the execution of the body of the method is complete.
>
> **Constructor parameters** (§8.8.1) name argument values passed to a
>   constructor.
>
> For every parameter declared in a constructor declaration, a new
>   parameter variable is created each time a class instance creation
>   expression (§15.9) or explicit constructor invocation (§8.8.7) invokes
>   that constructor. The new variable is initialized with the
>   corresponding argument value from the creation expression or
>   constructor invocation. The constructor parameter effectively ceases
>   to exist when the execution of the body of the constructor is
>   complete.
>
> **An exception parameter** is created each time an exception is caught by
>   a catch clause of a try statement (§14.20).
>
> The new variable is initialized with the actual object associated with
>   the exception (§11.3, §14.18). The exception parameter effectively
>   ceases to exist when execution of the block associated with the catch
>   clause is complete.
>
> **Local variables** are declared by local variable declaration statements
>   (§14.4).
>
> Whenever the flow of control enters a block (§14.2) or for statement
>   (§14.14), a new variable is created for each local variable declared
>   in a local variable declaration statement immediately contained within
>   that block or for statement.

You should also read about [variable scope](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3), which describes where some named entity can be used within your application.

> Therefore my question is why would they classify Parameters and Local
>   variables as different categories of variables if they contain the
>   same scope

As you can see from the descriptions above, they do not contain the same scope and therefore need to be differentiated.

Answer (score 3):

Because they don't necessarily have the same scope.

Take this case:

```
// this is garbage code
public void doSomething(int foo) {
    int meh = 0;
    while (true) {
         // can access foo and meh
         int blah = meh++;
         if (blah == foo) {
             break;
         }
    }
    // won't compile, can't access blah anymore
    System.out.println(blah);
    // will compile
    System.out.println(foo);
    // will compile as well
    System.out.println(meh);
}
```

Comment: @someone because it references a variable that's scoped within the `while` loop, after completion of the loop, where it's not accessible anymore. Which is a good example (in my opinion) of the difference between parameters and local variables as per scope. **Edit** of course this is an example. Local variables can **also** be in the same scope as arguments - `meh` shares scope with `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are initialized in the method, while parameters are passed into the method.

```
    public void method(int abc) //parameter
        int xyz = 0; //local variable
```

Comment: I said despite their uses but ok

Comment: This doesn't involve their uses. If you're passing in a parameter you are not initializing it, thus it is a different type of variable.