# Return statement cannot find the local variable inside the method

Tags: java, class, oop

I am a 2nd year CS student and trying to fix a simple method. The logic is fairly easy but somehow I still get an error although I don't know what's wrong here.

The problem :

[image]

The beginning of the class:

```
private Integer dt[];
private int size;
IntManager(int k){
    dt = new Integer[k]; 
    size = 0;
}
```

The method inside the class:

```
public Integer max(){
  //return largest value in dt; null if size == 0
    if (size == 0) return null;
    else{
        Integer biggest = dt[0];//trouble here; changing to int won't help & var name also  
        for (int j = 0; j < size ; j++) {
            if (dt[j] < biggest) biggest = dt[j];
        }
    }
    return biggest;
}
```

Main class:

```
IntManager num = new IntManager(100);
    for (int j = 0; j < 20 ; j++) {
        int x = (int)(Math.random()*10);
        num.add(x);
    }
    num.add(57);
    System.out.println(num);

    System.out.println(num.found(5));//Ignore this


    System.out.println(num.max());
```

Comment: Move `return biggest;` inside the `else` branch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameter scope vs local variable scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233920/parameter-scope-vs-local-variable-scope)

Comment: @Turamarth thank you it worked. Weird thing though

Comment: @GheorgheDonciu: would you replace your image of an error with the text of the same? It is easier for people to work with in text (it can be copy+pasted, it works with screen readers, the search engines pick it up). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your blocks

```
public Integer max(){
 //return largest value in dt; null if size == 0
    if (size == 0) return null;
    else{
        Integer biggest = dt[0];//trouble here; changing to int won't help     & var name also  
        for (int j = 0; j < size ; j++) {
            if (dt[j] < biggest) biggest = dt[j];
        }
    }
    return biggest;
}
```

You're declaring biggest within the scope of that else block, so it is not visible when you reach your return statement. To correct it you should have something like:

```
public Integer max(){
 //return largest value in dt; null if size == 0
    Integer biggest = dt[0]
    if (size == 0) return null;
    else{
        ;//trouble here; changing to int won't help     & var name also  
        for (int j = 0; j < size ; j++) {
            if (dt[j] < biggest) biggest = dt[j];
        }
    }
    return biggest;
}
```

Comment: I know about that and I tried but it didn't helped. Any other suggestions?

Comment: well you have `if (dt[j] < biggest) biggest = dt[j];` which is checking if `dt[j]` is **less** than `biggest`. It should be the opposite `if (dt[j] > biggest) biggest = dt[j];` @GheorgheDonciu

Answer (score 2):

Your **biggest** variable is defined inside the ifelse scope therefore is not visible outside of that segment
declare the Integer as a hole method variable...

## Example:

```
public Integer max(){
      Integer biggest=null;
        if (size != 0) {
            Integer biggest = dt[0]; 

            for (int j = 0; j < size ; j++) {
                if (dt[j] < biggest) biggest = dt[j];
            }
        }
        return biggest;
    }
```

Comment: I tried that and the method didn't perform what it is supposed to do. It just returned 0 instead of 57. Something is not working properly here. Any other suggestions?